# Screen resolution according to tkinter and PIL?

Tags: python, tkinter, pixel, imagegrab

According to tkinter my screen has (1536x864)px while according to PIL my screen has (1920x1080)px, what is going on here and is there a way to solve this?

So I was writing a little program that makes a transparent tkinter window that i can move arround. When I press a button, the program uses the winfo.rootx, winfo_rooty, width and height to calculate where the four edges of the frame are. These are then passed to PIL ImageGrab.grab for it to screenshot the window.

```
    def capture(self,event=None):
        self.update()
        x0 = self.winfo_rootx() #left wall
        y0 = self.winfo_rooty() #top wall
        x1 = x0 + self.width #right wall
        y1 = y0 + self.height #bottom wall
        img = ImageGrab.grab(bbox=(x0,y0,x1,y1))
```

When I had the tkinter window in the top left, the plot was perfect, however when I moved the window over towards the bottom right, it captured a rectangle, different from my tkinter frame.

It must be about 2hours later that I noticed what was wrong: according to tkinter my screen has (1536x864)px
while according to PIL my screen has (1920x1080)px. What is going on here?

Correct image top left: Red is the frame that is capturing, blue is the captured frame.
[image: Correct image top left]

Wrong image bottom right: Red is the frame that is capturing, blue is the captured frame:
[image: Wrong image bottom right]

I managed to fix this by adding a factor 1920/1536=1.25 so that the output of tkinter gets upscaled to use as input to PIL.

Comment: Do you know what your actual physical screen dimensions are? Are either of the values correct?

Comment: Have you checked the scaling settings?  Many computers have a default scaling that doesn't  match the resolution capabilities of the display.

Comment: @BryanOakley My actual dimensions are 1920x1080.

Comment: @Rory Yes thats the issue, my display was at 125% tnx a lot! Still strange one lib gets it right while the other doesn't.